# How to fully execute jQuery animations without queuing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I've looked at these 3 links how to execute jQuery animations without queuing and none of them worked for my project. I guess I'm implementing them not in the right way but I've read full info with examples and still nothing. There are these links:

- https://css-tricks.com/full-jquery-animations/
- [jQuery animation without queuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14785501/jquery-animation-without-queuing)
- http://www.2meter3.de/code/hoverFlow/

The problem in my project is when you click the `#new-quote` button multiple times quickly, the animation starts doing crazy things.

```js
var getNewQuote = function() {
  var quote = {};
  $.ajax({
    url: "https://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&post",
    success: function(d) {
      quote.text = $(d[0].content).text().trim();
      quote.author = d[0].title;
    },
    datatype: "json",
    async: false,
    cache: false
  });

  return quote;
};

var getRandomColor = function() {
  var colors = [
      "#ff9966",
      "#7f00ff",
      "#396afc",
      "#0cebeb",
      "#06beb6",
      "#642b73",
      "#36d1dc",
      "#cb356b",
      "#3a1c71",
      "#ef3b36",
      "#159957",
      "#000046",
      "#007991",
      "#56ccf2",
      "#f2994a",
      "#e44d26",
      "#4ac29a",
      "#f7971e",
      "#34e89e",
      "#6190e8",
      "#3494e6",
      "#ee0979"
    ],
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  return colors[randomNumber];
};

var updateText = function($t, qt) {

  var twitter = "https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?hashtags=quotes&related=freecodecamp&text=";
  twitter += '"' + qt.text + '" ';
  twitter += qt.author;

  var tumblr = "https://www.tumblr.com/widgets/share/tool?posttype=quote&tags=quotes,freecodecamp&caption=";
  tumblr += qt.author;
  tumblr += "&content=";
  tumblr += qt.text;
  tumblr += "&canonicalUrl=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tumblr.com%2Fbuttons&shareSource=tumblr_share_button";

  var $icon = $("<i class='fa fa-quote-left'>")
    .prop("aria-hidden", true);

  $t.find(".quote-text").html("").append($icon, qt.text);
  $t.find(".quote-author").html("- " + qt.author);
  $("#tweet-quote").attr("href", twitter);
  $("#tumblr-quote").attr("href", tumblr);
};

var calcNewHeight = function(q) {
  var $temp = $("<div>", {
    class: "quote-container temp",
  }).appendTo($("body"));
  $temp.append($("<div>", {
    class: "quote-text"
  }), $("<div>", {
    class: "quote-author"
  }));
  updateText($temp, q);
  var h = $temp.height() + 40;
  $temp.remove();
  return h;
};

var changeColor = function(newColor) {
  $("body, .button:not(#new-quote)").animate({
    backgroundColor: newColor
  });
  $("#new-quote").animate({
    color: newColor
  });
  $(".quote-text, .quote-author").css("color", newColor);
  if ($("#modStyle").length === 0) {
    $("head").append(
      "<style id='modStyle'>#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";}</style>"
    );
  } else {
    $("head style#modStyle").html("#new-quote:before {background:" + newColor + ";}");

  }
};

var getQuote = function(e) {
  var nq, nc, nh = 0;

  $(".quote-container").queue(function() {
      nq = getNewQuote();
      nc = getRandomColor();
      $(".quote-container").children().css("opacity", 0);
      changeColor(nc);
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .queue(function() {
      nh = calcNewHeight(nq);
      $(".quote-container, #new-quote").animate({
        height: nh / 16 + "rem",
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });

      $(".quote-container").animate({
        padding: "2.5rem"
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });

      $("#new-quote").animate({
        padding: "2.5rem .75rem"
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .queue(function() {
      updateText($(".quote-container"), nq);
      $(".quote-container").children().fadeTo(750, 1);
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
};

$(function() {
  $("#new-quote").on("click", getQuote);
  $(".quote-container, #new-quote").css({
    visibility: "visible",
    height: 0
  });
  $("#new-quote").css("padding", "0 .75rem");
  getQuote();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #333;
  color: #333;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

.v-wrap {
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.v-wrap:before {
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.quote-container {
  width: 31.25rem;
  background: #fff;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  border-radius: 0.1875rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  padding: 0 2.5rem;
}

.quote-text {
  font-size: 1.625rem;
}

.quote-text i {
  margin-right: 0.6rem;
}

.quote-text p {
  display: inline;
}

.quote-author {
  font-size: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0.4rem 2rem 0;
  text-align: right;
}

.button {
  padding: 0.75rem;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1rem;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: .1875rem;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}

.button:not(#new-quote):hover {
  opacity: .8 !important;
}

.button:not(#new-quote) {
  min-width: 1rem;
  min-height: 1rem;
}

.button i {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#new-quote {
  white-space: nowrap;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  height: 50%;
  border-top-left-radius: 0;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background: #fff !important;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 0.25625rem;
  color: #333;
  visibility: hidden;
}

#new-quote:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 0.0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(0);
  transform: scaleY(0);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out;
}

#new-quote:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleY(1);
  transform: scaleY(1);
}

footer {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
  margin: 1rem 0;
}

footer a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

footer a:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: .0625rem;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
  transition: all .3s ease-in-out 0s;
}

footer a:hover:before {
  visibility: visible;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/911574fea4.js"></script>
<div class="v-wrap">
  <div class="quote-container" style="">
    <div class="quote-text">
    </div>
    <div class="quote-author"></div>
    <a id="tweet-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a id="tumblr-quote" class="button"><i class="fa fa-tumblr"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div id="new-quote" class="button">New quote</div>
  <footer>
    <a href="https://codepen.io/Kestis500">Created by LukasLSC</a>
  </footer>
</div>
```

Link to the codepen project: https://codepen.io/Kestis500/pen/opWGNY?editors=0010

Link to the jsfiddle project: https://jsfiddle.net/z5hds4Lp/2/

***Note:***
I can't explain why AJAX doesn't work here, using codepen or jsfiddle everything with AJAX is ok.

Comment: My recommendation is to disable that button when ajax is processing the request.

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep in mind that and try it soon, however, how to achieve my desired result without disabling button?

Comment: Am... It's not actually a button. I've tried using `$("#new-quote").prop("disabled", true);`, didn't work.

Comment: `using codepen or jsfiddle everything with AJAX is ok` So where are the links? Anyway, you don't have to use `async: false` it is deprecated and block the UI.

Comment: What do you mean it's blocking the UI and is deprecated? What should I use instead? I'll update the question with these links soon.

Answer (score 0):

I did not encounter any particularly "crazy things" by rapidly clicking the Get Quote button. But here is one option for exercising more control over the animation by introducing an animation state.

Add a boolean variable

`var animating = false`;

Toggle the true/false value during animation. If it is already animating, don't let another animation get called.

```
var getQuote = function(e) {
  if (animating) return;    // If already animating, don't let it call again
  animating = true;         // Tell the state that it is animating
  var nq, nc, nh = 0;

  $(".quote-container").queue(function() {
      nq = getNewQuote();
      nc = getRandomColor();
      $(".quote-container").children().css("opacity", 0);
      changeColor(nc);
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .queue(function() {
      nh = calcNewHeight(nq);
      $(".quote-container, #new-quote").animate({
        height: nh / 16 + "rem",
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });

      $(".quote-container").animate({
        padding: "2.5rem"
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });

      $("#new-quote").animate({
        padding: "2.5rem .75rem"
      }, {
        duration: 1000,
        queue: false
      });
      $(this).dequeue();
    })
    .queue(function() {
      updateText($(".quote-container"), nq);
      $(".quote-container").children().fadeTo(750, 1);
      $(this).dequeue();
      animating = false;    // When the animation is done, set animating back to false.
    })
};
```

Comment: I've done what you said, but, unfortunately, it still keeps going: https://jsfiddle.net/z5hds4Lp/3/.

Comment: What is the issue that you are experiencing? Please provide more detail.

Comment: I'll make a video, please wait.

Comment: I do not have any other immediate suggestions. But be aware that the issue is happening in Chrome, whereas in Firefox this does not happen.

Comment: It takes no effect on my project code. Try to remove these booleans and it's the same result.